# Problem Upgrading from12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I recently tried to upgrade my system to 13.4, but in the middle of the the upgrade, system crashed. When I try to restart it goes to a slow and sluggish mode. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bear with the slowness. Once the system starts, you will have to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` from console to finish the upgrade.

If this command gives any error right at the beginning, then you can try using `sudo dpkg -a --configure` to fix your system.

Comment: "sudo apt-get -f install" Might help too.